# Alternate proof showinf the below claim

Tags: graph-theory

The sides and diagonals of a regular octagon are colored black or red. Show that there are atleast $7$ monochromatic triangles with vertices in the vertices of the octagon.

- My method was this :        .          Consider a vertex, its a part of $7$ lines . The largest possible mumber of pairs of line of different colours that use this vertex is $12$ , no of pairs of different lines $12*8 = 96$ , triangles which are not monochromatic are $48$ , total triangles possible are $\binom{8}{3} = 56$, therefore chromatic triangles possible are $8$ .

> If its correct approach can this be solved with another approach like as in considering the $7$ vertices connected to a vertex ? Or maybe using the fact of $2$ chromatic triangles in $6$ vertices case ?

Comment: You may or may not have differing results depending on the parity of number of vertices (regular polygons with an even number of sides have diagonals that intersect the centre of the polygon; ones with an odd number of sides do not).  Not sure if it matters though, since you are really only counting vertices and lines.

Comment: So you've been asked to prove that there are $7$ monochromatic triangles but you've proven that there must be $8$. Nice work, couldn't find a fault in your proof (except that it could be written in a slightly more verbose and explanatory way).

Comment: The general case of this and the previous results is known as Goodman's theorem. (See [Goodman, *On sets of acquaintances and strangers at any party*](https://doi.org/10.2307/2310464).)

Comment: Thats really nice , just one thing what would we take when total non monochromatic triangles comes to be 31.5 in the previous problem i posted, will we take it as 32 non monochromatic  or 31 and why , you may reply there if possible @MishaLavrov